# I want to add a handler for buildbot's waterfall page

Tags: buildbot

I want to be able to make changes to waterfall page of Buildbot. I can make changes in the jinja2 template. But if I want to add my own handlers how do I do it?

Comment: Could you some more information, maybe some code also, please?

Comment: I want to have a button after each build and link it to a local zip file of the build, so that users can download from it. But i have no clue where to start.